# Swift OS X game center

Tags: swift, macos, game-center

i searched all over the web without luck, is there any tutorial on how implement game center with swift in OSX?

I found only example for IOS, but no one for OS X...The problem is that OS X games doesn't have GameViewController.swift but AppDelegate.swift and all the tutorial i found is based on IOS architecture.

i should use

```
     GKGameCenterViewController
```

or another protocol?

Can you tell me where i can find a simple tutorial to use game center with Swift in a OS X game?

Answer (score 1):

Just head over to the Apple Documentation, where there's a guide for iOS and OS X.

> Developing a Game Center-Aware Game

Klick [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH1-SW1) to get there.

Comment: Apple Documentation is very useful...but i'd like to see also a simple example on how implement Game Center in an OS X Project in practical terms.

Comment: For example Apple Documentation refers to 'GKDialogController' for OSX, but there is an example only for objective C, not for Swift. There is a lack of support for Swift programmer in my opinion.